# Generate QR from file

Tags: qr-code

Is it possible to generate an entire file from a QR code? I don't mean the file text contents, but the entire file, be able to reproduce it scanning the QR.

If I could generate the QR with a command or portable application much better than uploading my file to a server which can cause data leaks.

Comment: How large is the file? Observe how QR codes grow as the stored text gets longer. It will be impractical for any file that's not tiny. Also, how are you going to make sure the QR code won't leak? Why not simply encrypt the file?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clarify what you are attempting to do. What is your use case? Are you intending to create a QR code that, when scanned, will create a file on the user's device? (Also note that your title says "Generate QR from file" which seems to be the opposite of your question.)

Comment: @slhck I want to do both things, generate the QR from a file then recover the file taking a picture.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand how QR codes work. They are only a specification on how to encode data. They do not inherently tell end-user applications what to do with that data.

The fact that QR codes work for hyperlinks, telephone numbers, or 2-factor authentication is due to the world having agreed on what the content of the QR code should do. For instance, your camera reading a QR code with a URL will tell the browser to open that URL. See [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents) for more info:

> 2D barcodes encode text, generally, but that text can represent many things. Commonly, 2D barcodes encode text that represents a URL, like https://google.com/m. This is a special string of text since it is recognizable as a URL by readers, and therefore can be acted upon: the reader can open the URL in a browser.

That means that you could, in theory, develop your own data format for QR codes that can create files on an end-user device. That (arguably very naive) format could look like this:

```
filename:foo.png|data:iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAh4AAALQCAYAAADfIXmOAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAIABJREFUeF7snQnYVdP3xxcyZ86czGQekhSZpdIgkShp0EAJJZQkQylJUWgQFaUimpQhUyFK5llk9jMnGTL+n8/236/Tde57731733vOfc93P09PdM85e+3vWmft715r7X3W+Pvvv/82NSEgBISAEBACQkAI5AGBNUQ88oCyuhACQkAICAEhIAQcAiIeMgQhIASEgBAQAkIgbwiIeOQNanUkBISAEBACQkAIiHjIBoSAEBACQkAICIG8ISDikTeo1ZEQEAJCQAgIASEg4iEbEAJCQAgIASEgBPKGQKKIxxvPLs8bsOpICMQdgUqV17Gtq6wXd
```

You would have to write your own application that stores QR code data in this format based on a filename and content you pass to it.

Then, you would have to write your own client-side applications that can parse this format. Your application has to store the file with the specified name and the data contents on the user's device.

But: that would all be a nightmare in terms of security. Seriously. Don't do it. Having an application interface that allows arbitrary writing of files with unknown contents to an end-user device sounds like trouble to me.

All in all, you should re-evaluate your use case. (Which I don't know since you did not explain what you *actually* need this for.)

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia
[QR code - Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage):

> The amount of data that can be stored in the QR code symbol depends on the data type (mode, or input character set), version (1, ..., 40, indicating the overall dimensions of the symbol, i.e. 4 × version number + 17 dots on each side), and error correction level. The maximum storage capacities occur for version 40 and error correction level L (low), denoted by 40-L:
>
> Maximum character storage capacity (40-L)
> Character refers to individual values of the input mode (data type).
>
> | Input mode | Max. characters | Bits/char. | Possible characters, default encoding |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Numeric only | 7,089 | 31⁄3 | 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 |
> | Alphanumeric | 4,296 | 51⁄2 | 0–9, A–Z (upper-case only), space, $, %, *, +, -, ., /, : |
> | Binary/byte | 2,953 | 8 | ISO 8859-1 |
> | Kanji/kana | 1,817 | 13 | Shift JIS X 0208 |
>
> <sup>[original table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Jrw.jpg)</sup>

The answer to your question is then positive - as long as the file
fits within the above limits.

You might need to write your own encode/decode programs for such
usage, but in principle this is entirely possible, although it
would only be for small files.

Answer (score -2):

You can look into [qrencode](https://linux.die.net/man/1/qrencode). And then you can generate QR codes from the command line as needed and save the generated code as.

Example:

```
$ qrencode -o qrcode.png 'Hello World!'
```

There are many flags that should help you achieve your task. But you have to read the manual as per your needs.

Comment: `qrencode` is only for text being input from the terminal.

Comment: @Smeterlink As slhck explained that's not a problem. It's not just for text - it's for bytes, which usually happen to correspond to represent text, but it's not a hard requirement. `qrencode` happens to be console-oriented, but you can feed any kind of data into it using `xargs` or wrap it into a GUI.